# Update Playframework in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

I was trying to build some Test Cases in my PlayFramework App, when I discovered that some elements of the 2.4.x version of the play framework couldn`t be imported. (For example: the RequestBuilder [Link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestBuilder.html) or Databases, which where added in recent version of the play framework.

I figured my Play Framework version is outdated, and since then trying to update it, so that I can use those elements.

What I tried.

- I updated the scala Plugin in IntelliJ
- Updated via `activator update` and then reimport the project

Both didn't work and I am still unable to use Plays `RequestBuilder` or `Databases` (Updating via activator did broke my project so hard that I had to reclone the whole thing from my repo)

Could anybody help me out here

Comment: did you try to run your app from command line?

Comment: Have you tried to run `activator clean` and then re-import the project again?

Comment: I had issues importing a Play 2.4 project in Intellij IDEA as well, however not with the dependencies you've listed but with JUnit not being imported properly. You could check your projects' .idea/libraries folder if it contains an XML file for your dependency and if the file contains valid paths to the dependency.
Otherwise I would recommend to file a bug a Jetbrains if you can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you must change three files to update the Play version :

project/plugins.sbt (play version, update the plugins to their last version too)

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.3")
```

project/build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.11
```

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Then update your SBT project using Intellij IDEA. As Peanut said, you can try to do an activator clean before importing the SBT project again.